# How can I disable direct access to a folder html page?

Tags: html, browser, server

Heres the scenario: In the root of the server i have an folder named "data".
In this folder is a file named "random-file.html". Now I want, that you can't see the contents of the folder "data" if you type "domain.com/data/" but you have access to the file "random-file.html" and can it.

Comment: place an empty index.html file in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. You can hide it using .htaccess. I assume you use xampp server. You can see this [1] https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/apache/115/htaccess-file-dir-security.html

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the most secure practice is to keep sensitive files outside the root of your webserver all together. Create a folder on the VM or server which your app is hosted and have your application read/write/use it from there.

Most serverside frameworks/tools have a "websecrets" type functionality you could use. But this step above is my 'framework agnostic' advice.